# How to access Angular's form array in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloServiceService } from 'src/app/hello-service.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-say-hello',
  templateUrl: './say-hello.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./say-hello.component.css']
})

export class SayHelloComponent implements OnInit 
{
  hello = {
    greetings: ''
  }

  objForm: FormGroup;
  ordersData = [
  { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
  { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
  { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
  { id: 400, name: 'order 4' }
  ];
     
  constructor( private objHelloService: HelloServiceService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) 
  {  
    this.objForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: new FormArray([])
      });
       
      this.addCheckboxes();
      
  }

  private addCheckboxes() 
  {
    this.ordersData.forEach((o, i) => {
                                        const control = new FormControl(i === 0); // if first item set to true, else false
                                        (this.objForm.controls.orders as FormArray).push(control);
                                        console.log("QQQQQQQQQQQQ")
                                      });
  }
     
  submit()
  {
    const selectedOrderIds = this.ordersData
                      .filter(i => i !== null) //Filter array of orders by null check
                      .map(v => v.id)  //Get only ids out of array of orders
                      console.log(selectedOrderIds)  //[100, 200, 300, 400]

  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {  }

  submitted = false

  saveHello() 
  {
    const data = {
      greetings: this.hello.greetings
    };

    this.objHelloService.create(data).subscribe(
                                                  response => {
                                                                console.log(response);
                                                                this.submitted = true;
                                                              },
                                                  error => {
                                                              console.log("From say-hello.component.ts: ",error);
                                                            }
                                                );
  }

  newHello()
  {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.hello = {
                    greetings: ''
                  };
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="objForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of objForm.value.orders.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
      {{ordersData[i].name}}
  </label>
   
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, `addCheckboxes` is the function where data is getting pushed in the form object.

What is the way to access this from html?

I intend to display checkboxes on the browser. There are no checkboxes being displayed. Please tell me what is the proper way to write the for loop in html.

Comment: do u see any error ?

Comment: @YogendraR No, I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add following in your .ts

```
get objFormArray(): FormArray {
     return (<FormArray>this.objForm.get('orders'));
}
```

in your HTML you can say

```
*ngFor="let order of objFormArray.controls"
```

Comment: Please explain what was I doing previously in my code and why it was failing. I am new to do.

Comment: The way you have written in HTML objForm.value.orders.controls was wrong. You will never find controls in value. Try to console.log(objForm) after fillup data and you will get idea